# Ui5 SearchField - suggestions from multiple property names?

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5, abap

I have imported the Search help `O2USERNAME` as an oData service in ABAP.
I'd like to have a live suggestion field in UI5, but I can only get one filter to work at a time. The goal is to have suggestions from `Bname`, `NameLast` and `NameFirst`.

In the SAP Note [1671893 ODATA - convert $filter to ABAP select option](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1671893), it says that:

> All properties within an 'or_expression' must have the same name.
>
> Valid: "name eq 'Sven' or name eq 'Hugo'"
>
> Invalid: "name eq 'Sven' or age eq 20" "

But that is exactly what I need. Is there a workaround known to this?

Here is my View:

```xml
<SearchField id="searchField" width="50%" placeholder="search for..." enableSuggestions="true"
           search="onSearch" suggest="onSuggest"
           suggestionItems="{ path: '/O2usernameSet', sorter: { path: 'NameLast' } }">
    <suggestionItems>
        <SuggestionItem text="{Bname}" description="{path:'NameLast'} {path:'NameFirst'}"
             key="{Bname}"/>
    </suggestionItems>
</SearchField>
```

and my Controller:

```
onSuggest: function (oEvent) {
    var searchField = oEvent.getSource(),
        sQuery = searchField.getProperty("value"),
        filters1,filters2 = [],
        oBinding = searchField.getBinding("suggestionItems");
        filters2 = new Filter({
                                filters1: [
                                    new Filter("Bname", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery.toUpperCase())
                                     , new Filter("NameLast", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery) ,
                                     , new Filter("NameFirst", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery) 

                                ],
                                and: false
                            });
    oBinding.filter(filters2);

    oBinding.attachEventOnce('dataReceived', function (parentEvent) {
        searchField.suggest();
    }.bind(null, oEvent));
}
```

---

**The Error From the Backend with a correctly biuld filter is:**

> The following problem occurred: HTTP request failed500,Internal Server Error,{"error":{
>       "code":"/IWBEP/CM_MGW_RT/032",
>       "message":{
>           "lang":"de",
>           "value":"Interner Fehler aufgetreten. Wenden Sie sich an den Systemadministrator"
>       },
>       "innererror":{
>           "application":{
>               "component_id":"*removedByMe*",
>               "service_namespace":"*MY_NAMESPACE*",
>               "service_id":"*MY_SERVICE*",
>               "service_version":"0001"
>           },
>           "transactionid":"0BE63D492E4D0210E005CF86AE1FC269",
>           "timestamp":"20190621120505.9381020",
>           "Error_Resolution":{
>               "SAP_Transaction":"For backend administrators: run transaction /IWFND/ERROR_LOG on SAP Gateway hub system and search for entries with the timestamp above for more details",
>               "SAP_Note":"See SAP Note 1797736 for error analysis (https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1797736)"
>           },
>           "errordetails":[{
>               "code":"/IWBEP/CX_MGW_TECH_EXCEPTION",
>               "message":"Interner Fehler aufgetreten. Wenden Sie sich an den Systemadministrator",
>               "propertyref":"",
>               "severity":"error",
>               "target":""}
>           ]}
>       }
>   }

/IWFND/ERROR_LOG reveals the above metioned Note

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to have multiple text-fragments for each type of Filter? 
I mean can you for instance say NameFirst contains 'Sven' or 'Hugo' or NameLast contains 'LastName' or 'LastName2'?

If yes, I'll have to adjust my answer, if not:

your `orFilter1`, `orFilter2`, `orFilter3` shouldn't be arrays since they contain 1 Filter object each,

Secondly there is a minor error in your filter.push part. More precisly when you are creating the 'final' filter.

When creating a filter containing multiple filter-rules, the following notation is allowed:

```
new sap.ui.model.Filter(aFilters, bAnd);
```

**Note that aFilters is an array of filter-objects here**

But you are giving 4 parameters and I don't think that will work.

So back to your code, once you've changed your orFilter-arrays to objects, try this:

```
filter.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter({
        filters: [orFilter3, orFilter2, orFilter1], // equals aFilters in previous code sample
        and: false // equals bAnd in  previous code sample
    })
);
```

Comment: And it is possible to filter with or while staying within Bname
O2usernameSet?$filter=startswith(Bname, 'BnameOfMe') or startswith(Bname, 'BnameofSomeone')&$format=json

Comment: You can combine different text-fragments with and - with this i can produce the enties i dont want in the Gatewa client

Comment: Oh yes, you're right about that, actually that was one of the earlier versions. Now the filter is correct but i get an error from the backend: HTTP request failed500,Internal Server Error,{"error":{"code":"/IWBEP/CM_MGW_RT/032", ... }Leading to SAP Note 1797736 –

Comment: well I'm no expert in these kind of errors, could you include the entire Server Error?
The message might give more info since now there can be multiple reasons to have this error: server is down - incorrect implemented functions in backend - ...

Comment: Well the backend implemetaion is the imported valuehelp so no modification there
and i included the full error in the question

Comment: well that part is where my knowledge ends :/ this looks to me to be a backend issue

Comment: the component_id, service_namespapce and service_id look very strange to me, maybe you should check that? Sorry I can't help mmuch more there